# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter - "this should only be called when the cursor is valid"

Tags: android

I have an adapter extended from SimpleCursorTreeAdapter and attached to ExpandableListActivity.
SimpleCursorTreeAdapter  throws an exception every time orientation of device changed! (Only if at least 1 item is expanded)
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid"
my OnCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disciplines);
        dbHelper.open();
        dataCursor = dbHelper.getDisciplinesOneField();
        DisciplineAdapter adapter = new DisciplineAdapter(this, dataCursor,
                R.layout.discipline_row
                , new String[]{Discipline.NAME}
                , new int[]{R.id.discipline_row_name}
                , R.layout.lesson_child, new String[]{}, new int[]{});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }
```

My adapter:

```
private class DisciplineAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter{
        public DisciplineAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        }

        @Override
        protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
                boolean isLastChild) {
            super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);
                    // Filling my views here
        }


        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            long disciplineId = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            return dbHelper.getLessonsForDiscipline(disciplineId);
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? What is missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having almost exactly the same problem.  Although for me I'm using a Loader to populate the database and the resulting stack trace does not reference my code anywhere.

Comment: I didn't find any solution to this. Decided to use other views.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll start looking at my options.